# Sitecore update page install slow due to save event

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

On our current sitecore implementation we have bunch of custom "OnItemSaved" events that moves, renames, creates new folders etc based on item template.

What I've noticed is that this "OnItemSaved" get recursively called on package deployment. This causes the package deployment to be very slow.

I've included appropriate event disabler and template checks etc.

Could someone please help me whether it's possible to disable the custom events on package install or are there any good solutions to this problem?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a brilliant article from John West that describes the problem of infinite recursion with item save event and how to solve it. Hope this solves your problem.

http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2010/11/intercepting-item-updates-with-sitecore.aspx